# MySQL - How to run long (>14 hour) job over an SSH connection?

Tags: mysql

I need to run a MySQL script that, according to my benchmarking, should take over 14 hours to run. The script is updating every row in a 332715-row table:

```
UPDATE gene_set SET attribute_fk = (
    SELECT id FROM attribute WHERE
        gene_set.name_from_dataset <=> attribute.name_from_dataset AND
        gene_set.id_from_dataset <=> attribute.id_from_dataset AND
        gene_set.description_from_dataset <=> attribute.description_from_dataset AND
        gene_set.url_from_dataset <=> attribute.url_from_dataset AND
        gene_set.name_from_naming_authority <=> attribute.name_from_naming_authority AND
        gene_set.id_from_naming_authority <=> attribute.id_from_naming_authority AND
        gene_set.description_from_naming_authority <=> attribute.description_from_naming_authority AND
        gene_set.url_from_naming_authority <=> attribute.url_from_naming_authority AND
        gene_set.attribute_type_fk <=> attribute.attribute_type_fk AND
        gene_set.naming_authority_fk <=> attribute.naming_authority_fk
    );
```

(The script is unfortunate; I need to transfer all the data from `gene_set` to `attribute`, but first I must correctly set a foreign key to point to `attribute`).

I haven't been able to successfully run it using this command:

```
nohup mysql -h [host] -u [user] -p [database] < my_script.sql
```

For example, last night, it ran over 10 hours but then the ssh connection broke:

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

Is there any way to run this script in a way to better ensure that it finishes? I really don't care how long it takes (1 day vs 2 days doesn't really matter) so long as I know it will finish.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the remote machine ? If so you could just copy the script over there and run it locally inside the mysql server.

Comment: @gwg That query is running once for every row - which is why it's taking so long!  Can't you change it to operate on a set by updating the required value which you get by joining the data rather than selecting via a sub query?  That way you'll get a single execution - and a ludicrous performance improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you're getting poor performance for a 350k record update statement.  This is because you're setting based on the result of a sub query, and not updating as a set.  Thus you're running the statement once for each row.  Update as such:

```
UPDATE gene_set g JOIN attribute_fk a ON < all where clauses > SET g.attribute_fk = a.id.
```

This doesn't answer your question per se, but I'll be interested to know how much faster it runs.

Comment: Wow. That ran in maybe 2-5 seconds. I'm not sure what SO etiquette is here, since you didn't really answer the question—which makes searching for this question useless—but this is the answer I went with.

Comment: @gwg you make a very valid point on searching for the question.  Never-the-less, I'm glad it helped you out.  I said it would be ludicrous, I wouldn't have guess to such a degree though! :-) thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way might be to run it in a `screen` or `tmux` session.

Comment: I think if the network goes down even screen/tmux cannot keep the session open. It can keep a process running even after I detach from the tty, but wouldn't a ssh connection still get a "broke pipe" ?

Comment: Are you running the mysql statement on the same server as where mysql is? or do you have an ssh tunnel deployed and run mysql from your local machine? If it's the former, you start tmux on the server, not on your local machine and run mysql inside of that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i did it in past where I ran monolithic alter queries in remote server which take ages sometime :

```
mysql -h [host] -u [user] -p [database] < my_script.sql > result.log  2>&1 &
```

This way you don't need to wait for it as it will finish on its own time,You could customize and add select now() at start and end in your `my_script.sql`  to find out how long it took if you interest .

Things also to consider if applicable

1. Why this query take this long, can we improve it(eg : disable key checks .. , offline prepare the data and update with a temp table ..
2. Can we break the query to run in batches
3. What is the impact on rest of the DB 
   etc

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to the server you could copy it over and run it there with the following lines:

```
#copy over to tmp dir
scp my_script.sql user@remoteHost:/tmp/
#execute script on remote host
ssh -t user@remoteHost "nohup mysql \
    -h localhost -u [user] -p [database] < /tmp/my_script.sql &"
```

Comment: I do have access. So this will not drop, even if the ssh connection drops? Is this because it is not making an ssh connection to actually transfer the file?

Comment: It is making 2 ssh connection. First time it will just transfer the script which includes your mysql query. The second time it will ssh connect to the remote machine console, and execute the script over there. The ampersand will make sure the scripts run in the backround of the remote machine so the 2nd ssh connection can be dropped safely. If the remote machine is not restarted and your process will not be killed by someone else, you are safe and it will run as long as it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to do 300k updates with frequent commits instead of one single huge update. Doing that inc ase anything failed at you will maintain the changes already applied.

with some dimacic sql you can get all the lines in one go, later copy the file to your server ...